# Function Types Example Code / Need Explanation / Swift

Tags: swift, function, types, parameters, syntax

I'm currently learning Swift function types and the book gives me such code to demonstrate how we can use variables with functions:

```
var manipulateInteger: (Int, Int) -> Int

func multNumber(_ first: Int, _ second: Int) -> Int {
    return first * second
}

func addNumber(_ first: Int, _ second: Int) -> Int {
    return first + second
}

manipulateInteger = multNumber 

func doMath(_ manipulateInteger: (Int, Int) -> Int, _ a: Int, _ b: Int) {
    print("The result is: \(manipulateInteger(a, b))")
}

doMath(addNumbers, 5, 10)
```

The commentary for last step sounds like this:
*"By calling this new function with the addNumber for the first parameter, we use the new function to sum the numbers and output the result."*

I just want to understand if I'm getting it right: we changed **manipulateInteger** for **addNumbers** just to show that we can replace one function-parameter with another because they have the same function type? Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the variable `manipulateInteger`, the functions `multNumber` and `addNumber`, and the parameter `manipulateInteger` in the function `doMath` are all entities of the same type `(Int,Int) −> Int`.

You might have been confused by the fact that the closure variable var `manipulateInteger` and the parameter `manipulateInteger` in the function `doMath` share the same name. In reality, they are not related, and the function parameter could have any name.

Inside the function, when referring to the parameter `manipulateInteger`, you're using the value passed to that parameter when the function was called. This value could be any entity that matches the type `(Int,Int) −> Int`.

Using identical property names can easily become confusing. This example should help clarify:

```
class Calculator {
    var manipulateInteger: (Int, Int) -> Int

    init(manipulateInteger: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Int) {
        self.manipulateInteger = manipulateInteger
    }

    func doMath(_ manipulateInteger: (Int, Int) -> Int, _ a: Int, _ b: Int) {
        let functionParamResult = manipulateInteger(a, b)
        print("Result from the function parameter manipulateInteger: \(functionParamResult)")

        let classPropertyResult = self.manipulateInteger(a, b)
        print("Result from the class property manipulateInteger: \(classPropertyResult)")
    }
}

func multNumber(_ first: Int, _ second: Int) -> Int {
    return first * second
}

func addNumber(_ first: Int, _ second: Int) -> Int {
    return first + second
}

let calculator = Calculator(manipulateInteger: multNumber)
calculator.doMath(addNumber, 3, 5)
```

Executing this code produces the following console output:

```
Result from the function parameter manipulateInteger: 8
Result from the class property manipulateInteger: 15
```

Thus, from within the function body, you can access both its parameter and the object's property, even if they have the same name.

Comment: Yes indeed! Now it's clear to me.
Big spasibo to you!